# Access objects of a service from a controller in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, object, service

Here is a hard one:

I have a local JSON declared in my service and I want to access part of it from my controller. Right now I can manage to access it but only to a specific section (I can't parametrize it).
My intention is to access part of my JSON with a $rootScope variable or by passing an ID when I call my service, but I cant manage to make it (always returns undefined)

PS: sorry for my variables in Spanish but I make this code for me

Right now a simplified version of my code would be:

controller:

```
angular.module("demo").controller("myController", function($scope,$rootScope,subjectRequest) {

     $rootScope.asignaturaId = 'asignatura1';
     //$scope.asignaturaJson=subjectRequest.asignatura;//this works with my simple return (see below)
     $scope.asignaturaJson=subjectRequest.asignatura();
});
```

Service:

```
angular.module("demo").factory('subjectRequest',[ '$rootScope',function($rootScope){ 
asignaturas= {
    asignatura1:{
        id:1,
        profesorado: {
            profesor7:{ 
                title: {
                        text: 'horas Prof7'
                    },
                series: [{
                    id: 'c',
                    name: 'extra',
                    color: 'LightSkyBlue ',
                    data: [4,4,1,2,2,2,3,4,2,3,4,21]
                }, {
                    id: 'b',
                    name: 'Reservados',
                    color: 'red',
                    data: [1,1,4,1,4,3,2,1,1,5,3,1]
                }]
            },//end prof 7
            profesor8:{ 
                title: {
                        text: 'horas Prof8'
                    },                
                series: [{
                    id: 'c',
                    name: 'extra',
                    color: 'LightSkyBlue ',
                    data: [4,4,1,2,15,2,3,4,2,3,4,2]
                }, {
                    id: 'b',
                    name: 'Reservados',
                    color: 'red',
                    data: [11,1,4,1,4,3,2,1,1,5,3,1]
                }]
            }//end prof 8
        }//end profesorado          
    },//end asignatura 1

    asignatura2 : {
        id : 2,
        profesorado : {
            profesor9:{ 
                title: {
                        text: 'horas Prof4'
                    },
                series: [{
                    id: 'c',
                    name: 'extra',
                    color: 'LightSkyBlue ',
                    data: [4,4,1,2,2,2,3,4,2,3,4,21]
                }, {
                    id: 'b',
                    name: 'Reservados',
                    color: 'red',
                    data: [1,1,4,1,4,3,2,1,11,5,3,1]
                }]
            },//end prof 9

            profesor10:{ 
                title: {
                        text: 'horas Prof5'
                    },                
                series: [{
                    id: 'c',
                    name: 'extra',
                    color: 'LightSkyBlue ',
                    data: [14,4,1,2,15,2,3,4,2,3,4,2]
                }, {
                    id: 'b',
                    name: 'Reservados',
                    color: 'red',
                    data: [1,1,4,1,14,3,2,1,1,5,3,1]
                }]
            }//fin prof 10
        }//Fin Profesorado
    }//end asignatura 1
}//end asignaturas

//return { asignatura: asignaturas['asignatura1'] }; //this works

return { //I want to do something like this 
    asignatura: function(){
        return asignaturas[$rootScope.asignaturaId];
    } 

};
```

Answer (score 1):

please make this line

```
$scope.asignaturaJson=subjectRequest.asignatura;
```

as

```
$scope.asignaturaJson=subjectRequest.asignatura();
```

as your service return the function which return a response too.

I hope this will help you out!

Comment: yep, sorry I had that line for when I called the service with the call
return { asignatura: asignaturas['asignatura1'] }; //this works

it still doesn't work with that, but I will edit it in the question right now, thanks!